# Specialized class constructor based on enum value in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates

I need to create a class that describes a set of mathematical shapes. Let's say I want `Sphere`, `Cylinder`, `AABB` and `OBB`. For these, I will create an `enum` to represent them and would like user to pass in their desired shape type and provide the right inputs. For example:

```
// Shapes.h
enum ShapeType { Sphere, Cylinder, AABB, OBB, Count};

class Shape {
public: 
  Shape(ShapeType type, const float r, const float hl, const Vector3& minExtend, const Vector3& maxExtend);

private:
  ShapeType m_Type;
  float m_Radius;       // for Sphere and Cylinder end caps
  float m_halfLength;   // for Cylinders
  Vector3 m_minExtend;  // for AABB or OBB
  Vector3 m_maxExtend;  // for AABB or OBB
  Entity m_Parent;      // has position, orientation and scale; 
}
```

What's not ideal with this is that when creating instances of `Shape`, users are forced to provide all variables even when they don't need it. For example Sphere won't care about half length for example. Thus my question - is there a way to specialize my constructor based on `enum` value? For example, the below pseudo code:

```
// Shapes.h
enum ShapeType { Sphere, Cylinder, AABB, OBB, Count};

class Shape {
public: 
  Shape(ShapeType type = Sphere, const float r);
  Shape(ShapeType type = Cylinder, const float r, const float hl);
  Shape(ShapeType type = AABB, const Vector3& minExtend, const Vector3& maxExtend);
  Shape(ShapeType type = OBB, const Vector3& minExtend, const Vector3& maxExtend);

// ... same as above
```

Note I really don't want to use inheritance here and create a family of shapes as this class really is just used to hold some raw data before being sent to another process.

Comment: If you widen your sphere to ellipsoids you will want three radiuses. If you widen your cylinder to elliptical prisms you want two radiuses and a halflength. What do you think of the idea to always ask for three lengths, but offer a convenient way of entering "same as previous"? Or maybe ask for three values, each time whether it should be "length, same length as before, radius or same radius as before"; thereby eliminating a selection between sphere, ellipsoid, prism, cube, quadratic prism, or box; while giving more choice and hardly more input need.

Comment: I know the design won't be able to accommodate for all the possible shapes and that's okay. I just want to support these and that's good for now. Unless you have a really good way :)

Comment: do you know about [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) ? it's nearly what you are trying to implement.

Comment: Can you please clarify why using inheritance is not applicable in this case? ie using a class for each shape type, instead of one class representing them all. If you are required to use only a single class, then excuse me for missing the corresponding statement in the question.

Comment: Sounds good, added in the question. Overall I just want to hold simple fields that can be used to represent these shapes. They don't need any other functions and so inheritance would be a big overkill.

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to infer `type = Sphere` from the fact that only one parameter was provided?  `explicit Shape(const float r) : m_Type(Sphere),m_Radius(r) {}` and so forth.  Only for the last two would you actually accept the enumeration value to distinguish since they both take two `Vector3` values.

Comment: Yeah because the last two like you pointed out ... I'm wondering if I can use template specialization or something similar. However this is also not as explicit so I would like to see if I can be super explicit with templates.

Comment: The approach that the C++ standard library takes for this kind of problem is to define discrete trivial **types** for each of the variations. The constructors are overloaded based on the type that's passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way of doing this, if you provide the shape type as parameter. After all given

```
float r = 5;
ShapeType shape = getRandomShape(); // determine the shape to use via random number generation
Shape shape(shape, r);
```

The compiler has no way of telling whether `shape` is `ShapeType::Sphere`; the value is determined at runtime.

If you always provide the constants directly, there are ways of achieving something similar to this using a maker argument providing a object with a template parameter of type `ShapeType` for the compiler to be able to determine the correct constructor using overload resolution.

```
template<ShapeType>
struct ShapeTypeTag
{};

inline constexpr ShapeTypeTag<ShapeType::Sphere> SphereType;

class Shape {
public: 
    Shape(ShapeTypeTag<Sphere>, const float r);
    Shape(ShapeTypeTag<Cylinder>, const float r, const float hl);
    Shape(ShapeTypeTag<AABB>, const Vector3& minExtend, const Vector3& maxExtend);
    Shape(ShapeTypeTag<OBB>, const Vector3& minExtend, const Vector3& maxExtend);
};

...

Shape shape(SphereType, 5);
```

My preferred way of implementing this would be to create separate static member functions in `Shape` to create each shape type:

```
class Shape {
    template<ShapeType>
    ShapeTypeTag
    {
    };  

    Shape(const float r);
    Shape(const float r, const float hl);
    Shape(ShapeTypeTag<AABB>, const Vector3& minExtend, const Vector3& maxExtend);
    Shape(ShapeTypeTag<OBB>, const Vector3& minExtend, const Vector3& maxExtend);

public:

    static Shape createSphere(float r)
    {
        return r;
    }

    static Shape createCylinder(float r, float hl)
    {
        return { r, hl };
    }

    static Shape createAABB(const Vector3& minExtend, const Vector3& maxExtend)
    {
        return { ShapeTypeTag<ShapeType::AABB>{}, minExtend, maxExtend };
    }

    static Shape createOBB(const Vector3& minExtend, const Vector3& maxExtend)
    {
        return { ShapeTypeTag<ShapeType::OBB>{}, minExtend, maxExtend };
    }
};

...

Shape shape = Shape::createSphere(5);
```

Comment: Saw this question a while back and came back to say pretty much the same thing. As a theoretical user of the class I much prefer functions with names that tell me what I'm creating rather than having to guess which constructor to use and what parameters it needs.

Comment: For this solution one could also use std::integral_constant combined with the original enum to get distinct types.

Comment: If only my caller would call those static methods! Due to code base restriction, I think I have to use the constructors and I really like your tag method. Thanks for providing this solution! If I can use the static method one, I would prefer that as well.